# Is the force on the bob of a pendulum with respect to ground 0 at the bottom?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

Kind of a silly question, but imagine there's a pendulum swinging that has some fixed length l and it's at some angle $\theta$, then with respect to us, the forces on the bob are:
$$F_{rad} = mg \cos(\theta) - T$$ where $F_{rad}$ is radial component of net force and T is tension in the string, and
$$F_{Tan} = mg\sin(\theta)$$ where $F_{Tan}$ is tangential component of the net force on Bob. When the bob is at its lowest point, $\theta = 0$ and so the net force on bob is 0, but isn't there always a net force on bob that causes change in direction of velocity to make sure it doesn't move in a straight line? Or does that force only exist in bob's frame of reference?

Comment: Are you sure that $T=mg$ at the bottom?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think that is my central problem, we say that T - mg = F_c where F_c is centripetal force but isn't centripetal force just the tension in the string?

Comment: I'm thinking Tension in the string is greater than mg, but I can't say why would that be the case? Isn't tension just the reactive force?

Comment: Replace string with a spring then think about it. I think you should get it.

Comment: I think you're saying the string gets stretched which would make sense but don't we assume that the length of the string is constant?

Answer (score 3):

No, tension in the string at lowest point can be found from Newton's Second law:
$$\mathbf {F_{net}}=m\mathbf a$$
At lowest point, due to circular motion, we will have radial acceleration $\frac {v^2}{r}$. So, we have:
$$T-mg=\frac {mv^2}{r}$$
If you know the initial value of $\theta$, you can also find out the value of $T$ in terms of $\theta$ by making use of energy conservation to find $v$ at the lowest point.

Comment: That makes sense, but what causes this extra centripetal force? Why is tension in the string more than force of gravity? Is the string getting stretched?

Comment: No string is not getting stretched. The centripetal acceleration is present whenever a body undergoes curvilinear motion. It is the acceleration necessary to change the velocity of a point.